# Protractor : Unable to write protactor test case for a scenario

Tags: angularjs, protractor

I have to test e2e a SPA application build with AngularJS using prtractor. 
where html looks like below:

```
<h4 class="list-group-item-heading">{{vm.firstName}} {{vm.lastName}}</h4>
```

Is there any way to get the firstname and lastName out of it?
And also the controller has vm.Email but never binded to the view, how to get the value in protractor ?

Unit test case:

```
 var firstName = element(by.binding('vm.item.firstName')).getText();
 var secondName = element(by.binding('vm.item.lastName')).getText();
```

In this case firstName and lastName comes equal with value is concatenation of two values.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In protractor tests you are testing your app from user's (and browser's) perspective. Because of that you have access to elements that are accessible to the end-user, so available in HTML code. That's why vm.Email will not be accessible.

As for example you provided, if you want to test those particular elements, you can do that in two ways.

1. Enclose bindings in separate tags, e.g. `span`:

   `<span>{{vm.firstName}}</span> <span>{{vm.lastName}}</span>`

and then use this:

```
var firstName = element(by.exactBinding('vm.firstName')).getText();
var secondName = element(by.exactBinding('vm.lastName')).getText();
```

2. Do the same, but use `ng-bind`:

   `<h4 class="list-group-item-heading"><span ng-bind="vm.firstName"></span> <span  ng-bind="vm.lastName"></span></h4>`

and then use:

```
var firstName = element(by.exactBinding('vm.firstName')).getText();
var secondName = element(by.exactBinding('vm.lastName')).getText();
```

or this:

```
var firstName = element(by.binding('vm.firstName')).getText();
var secondName = element(by.binding('vm.lastName')).getText();
```

Check the docs [here](http://angular.github.io/protractor/#/api?view=ProtractorBy).